# Getting a nameserver for a domain

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, nameservers

I want to host my domain mydomain.com on a personal server, but my registrar asks me for my nameservers. Would it be possible to create a nameserver ns.mydomain.com and point it to the static IP that my hosting PC has?

In other words is it possible to set the hosting machine as the nameserver also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. THis is fine to do, as long as you have a name "Server" running on that machine. Another option is to use Amazon Route 53 as your name server. Its pennies per month and more reliable than your own server.

Comment: didn't know you actually have to have a server for that. installed bind9 and it's running great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the nameserver at your domain-registrar as well.
If your domain is xdomain.com and is registered through aRegistrar.com, there should be an option in the aRegistrars panel to create a NS authoritative record and point the new nameserver to an IP.
This is a different record from the A record you have to create to your nameserver hoster.

Answer (score 0):

If you host your domain in your own server(ie., vps/dedicated server).
 You can have the nameservers with your domain name.
 Like for **adomain.com** 
Then, the nameservers will be
 **ns1.adomain.com** and **ns2.adomain.com**.